# Blazor: How to use onkeyup with parameter and KeyboardEventArgs

Tags: blazor

Wenn the user set the focus to a link and presses a key, I need to register it, proof the key and get the a parameter from the link.

I know to read the key without a parameter and I know to transfer a parameter. But I can't figure out how to do both.

**How can I get a parameter (document) and the KeyboardEventArgs (or key) from the link?**

```
@foreach (var document in DocumentList)
{
    <a tabindex="0" type="button" @onclick="() => ShowDocument(document)" 
    @onkeyup="OnDocumentKeyUp(document)">@document.Doname</a>
}

@code{
    private void OnDocumentKeyUp(Do document, KeyboardEventArgs e) // THIS IS MY WISH, BUT NOT WORKING
    {
        if (e.Code is "Enter" or "NumpadEnter" or " " or "Space")
        {
            ShowDocument(document);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: `@onkeyup="e => OnDocumentKeyUp(document, e)"`

Answer (score 0):

Following example you can implement On Search Text Box Enter Event Search the Results.

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center position-relative my-1">
        <span class="bi bi-search position-absolute ms-6"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid w-250px" name="searchText" @bind="@SearchPhrase" @bind:event="oninput" @onkeypress="e => SearchKeyword(e, 100)" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
private string? SearchPhrase { get; set; }
    
public async Task SearchKeyword(KeyboardEventArgs e, long? _sectionID)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
        {
            await SearchRecords(_sectionID.ToString());
        }
    }
```